# What is this problem called?

Tags: algorithms

I work in telecom domain as an engineering governance analyst. I have an interesting problem but not sure what is it called so I can further research and find a solution.

In optical network services, everything is physical and dependent upon the optical spectrum i.e. the wavelength of the light itself which travels in an optical fibre. A telecom optical infrastructure as I am sure you can imagine is a mesh network connecting different building through these optical fibers.

To make it simpler, you can assume a spectrum (optical fibre) as a highway with multiple lanes (wavelengths). These highways intersects with other highways (in a building/datacenter) so you have the flexibility to go into multiple direction by choosing a different highway at the intersection. Also all the highways have same number of lanes.

There are 2 rules to follow:

1. These lanes are dedicated in a highway, so once someone has booked a lane on a particular highway, no one else can use it.
2. We also cannot change the lane in our whole route, even if we switch the highway on an intersection.  So if we were in the blue lane in highway 1, once we reach an intersection and take highway 3, we can only switch to blue lane of highway 3 depending upon if it is free or not.

Problem Statement:
How to avoid spectrum wastage.

Description:
When an engineer delivers a wavelength based optical service to a customer, he has to pick a wavelength between Point A and Point Z. Customer is available on both end points and we are the connectivity provider in the middle.
The delivery engineer has to find the shortest path (which we have already taken care of) to be efficient and also choose the right wavelength which would traverse through  multiple buildings (intersections) and optical fibres (highways).

Like I said earlier, once a wavelength is picked you have stay in that wavelength from Point A to Point Z.  Let’s say the engineer finds multiple wavelengths which are free between these 2 points, when he reaches an intersection, he has to now decide which wavelength  would be the best to pick so that in future if someone else also has to switch from one highway to another on an intersection they have maximum possible options to pick from.

I think the below picture can explain it better:
[image]

Assuming above diagram is the existing state, if someone has to go from New York to London, there are only 2 lanes available, but it is more efficient to pick the green lane because it keeps more options open in case someone else from New York, Paris, or Frankfurt wants to go to London. They can simply use the blue lane (at least one of them can).

We have lot of such multi way intersections (not just 4 way) between Point A and Point Z and randomly picking a free lane which is free throughout the whole route causes other lanes getting blocked which leads to spectrum wastage.

Could you please help me understand what is this problem called? If you also have any idea how we can best approach to create a solution then it wound be great if you could share your thoughts on that.